# How to determine the name of the variable with maximum value in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have 3 values stored in the variables a,b and c. I want to find the greatest among them. The values of the variables are: a = 3, b = 6, and c = 2.
The result should be the name of the variable that contains the maximum value—the text b.

Comment: what have you tried, what doesnt work? homework?

Answer (score 4):

```
$a = 3
$b = 6
$c = 2

(Get-Variable -name a,b,c | Sort Value | Select -Last 1).Name
```

**Result: `b`**

This uses `Get-Variable` to return the variables `$a`, `$b` and `$c`, sorts the result by their value and then selects the last 1 from that sorted list (which as a result has the highest value) and returns it's `Name` property.